# how to open a folder navigation when button clicked in Android App?

Tags: android, file, explorer

How can I open a folder navagation in my Android apps. I dont want to use any third party app like AndExplorer or ASTRO.
I want a button in my app and when click on it,a particular folder may be ("/sdcard/mywebfolder") should upen and user then can browser its content.

Please help me to accomplish it.

Thanks
Parvendra

Answer (score 0):

Well without the use of third party apps you are going to need to code a file explorer or at least a view to display a certain folder's contents.

You could always just let the user select the program for the browsing via an intent, but I could understand not wanting to do that. Only downside is it means more work and more coding.

Comment: thanks Roflha, So you mean there is no way to open the Android native file explorer. Like we can open any file e.g. pdf using the "application/pdf" MIME using the appropriate intent. I am basically concern about the possibility of it. whether its possible or not. e.g can not we do something using this code    Uri startDir = Uri.fromFile(new File(ROOT_FOLDER));
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   intent.setDataAndType(startDir, "vnd.android.cursor.dir");
      ("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
  startActivity(intent);